# MAMP not working as 'localhost' but works with "127.0.0.1"

Tags: apache, server, localhost, mac, mamp

I just installed MAMP on Mac OSX 10.8.2.

When it is started, I'm not able to access the server through `http://localhost:8888` but when I visit `http://127.0.0.1:8888/` and it works fine.

Why is it so? and how can I make it work with when I type `http://localhost:8888`

Answer (score 6):

Open your host file `/etc/hosts` with a text editor and make sure it contains:

```
127.0.0.1    localhost
```

If it still doesn't work, run this command: `file -b /etc/hosts` and make sure the result is `ASCII English text` and nothing else. If it is not, use an editor such as TextWrangler or BBEdit to clean it up (use Unix end-of-line characters).

[Source: Apple Support Communities](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/4442142?start=0&tstart=0)

Comment: I used Unix end-of-line and this solved my problem.